# Field cancellation of small antennas nearby

Tags: antenna, radio

For example, two loop antennas in the same plane, but current in them is in anti phase. So that when viewed from afar field cancels out.

How can I calculate effect of this cancellation?

I expect it to be related to distance between antenas and wavelength they emit.

Goal is to use this to reduce unwanted emissions of these 'antennas'.

Bonus question: where does the energy go? Does it burn up in the process, heating something, or does this configuration makes the energy behave like it was never emitted at all?

We can take frequency of 3mhz (wavelength of about 100m), loop antenna diameter of 1cm, and distance between antenna centers of 3cm. But approximate solution is fine too, I just want to know general rule.

Comment: To start, need to know the spacing between the two antennas and the frequency.

Comment: [What happens to the energy when waves perfectly cancel each other?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23930/what-happens-to-the-energy-when-waves-perfectly-cancel-each-other) on Physics SE

Comment: Might want to look at this answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/557346/how-to-understand-grating-lobe-problem-in-broadside-array/557381#557381 .  You're combining 2 signals of equal amplitude but with a phase difference between them that's proportional to the spacing between the elements, the angle off boresite, and the frequency, or wavelength.